# How to Inspect Element using Safari Browser

Tags: safari, inspect-element

I am developing websites and creating applications. I want to know how to inspect an element through web browsers like safari.

In normal Chrome, Firefox, Explorer or any other browsers, we will right click the mouse button or press Function Key `F12` to view the `Inspect Element`. But it is not happening in the case of safari browser.

Share your thoughts!

Answer (score 229, accepted):

In your Safari menu bar click **Safari** > **Preferences** & then select the **Advanced** tab.

> Select:  "Show Develop menu in menu bar"

Now you can click **Develop** in your menu bar and choose **Show Web Inspector**

See the detailed guide here for more info:
[LINK](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/safari/enable-develop-menu/)

You can also right-click and press "Inspect element".

**EDIT**
As suggested by @dennis in the comments: If you dont see "Show Develop menu in menu bar" you may need to run `DevToolsSecurity -enable` in the console before the option is visible

Comment: I had to run the following command `DevToolsSecurity -enable` in the console before the above option was visible on OS X (10.14.6)

Answer (score 10):

Press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+ <kbd>,</kbd>, then click in show develop menu in menu bar. After that click <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to open and close the inspector.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

in menu bar click on Edit->preference->advance at bottom click the check box true that is for Show develop menu in menu bar now a develop menu is display at menu bar where you can see all develop option and inspect.

Comment: This answer is basically a duplicate of the one posted six months earlier, except with less detailed information and some typos introduced.